# Azure Data Factory For each over large table

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have this scenario: I have a table ~200k records, and I need to iterate over each row and call an azure function passing the table id as a parameter. The problem here is according to the documentation the ForEach activity has a maximum length of 100,000 items, I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the foreach scope. Is any workaround

[Image with my work flow](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kWTBCSVfY_FK1LYs7otQ3i9WoMasojuE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: How are you getting 200k records in first place, do you use a lookup?

Comment: Yes I'm using lookup

Answer (score 0):

Design a two-level pipeline where the outer pipeline with the ForEach activity iterates over an inner pipeline which does the individual row level action. The outer pipeline can take 5k records at a time and pass it to inner pipeline.